# Executing batch files using C# code

Tags: c#, shell, windows-services, sftp

I have two batch files to execute SFTP commands.

1. Inner batch file
2. Outer batch file

Inner batch file contains below code :

```
put D:\Source_Data\SFTP\Sample.xml
```

Outer batch file contains below code:

```
psftp -b D:\Source_Data\SFTP\Innerbatch.bat -l username -i D:\WebCash\privatekey.ppk @server.domain.com
```

Outer batch file internally calls inner batch file. How to execute the batch files using C# code?

Also I need to get the error code (i.e) whether the batch file is executed successfully or not in C# code.

I used the below code to execute the batch files.

```
Process p = null;
p = Process.Start(@"C:\Batch\file.bat");
p.WaitForExit(1000);
p.ExitCode;
```

but getting error. Required info does not be determined while process is executing.

Problem is Windows Service. I can able to run the batch file through normal Windows form application. But when I used the same code in Windows Service the process is not exiting.

Comment: Check out the `System.Diagnostics.Process` class.

Comment: I tried but my process is not finishing. Edited the question with my code. pls refer.

Comment: Should `Process.Start(@"Batchfilepath");` be `Process.Start(Batchfilepath);`?

Comment: yes.. typo error. My code is Process.Start(@"C:\Batch\File.bat")

Comment: If you execute the batch files from the Window's run command, do they run well? In how much time? Do the batch files require elevated privilidges?

Comment: Yes, I can able to execute successfully with in 2 mins...

Comment: @user3859666 Well then wait for two minutes before asking for the exit code: `p.WaitForExit();` will wait indefinitely or if a reasonable maximum time is, say, 3 minutes, `p.WaitForExit(3 * 60 * 1000);` In your code you are only waiting 1 second. See answer.

Comment: I have tried those codes already. Problem is When i execute the batch file through Windows command prompt it is running with in 1 min. But if i execute through code it is not finishing. I dont know how long it takes to execute though code. I waited for nearly 5 mins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `System.Diagnostics.Process` for this.

Based on your comments, the batch file can take up to 2 minutes to execute. I would implement the following code:

```
public static int ExecuteBatchFile(string batchFilePath, int timeout, bool killOnTimeout = false)
{
   using (var p = Process.Start(batchFilePath))
   {
       p.WaitForExit(timeout);

       if (p.HasExited)
           return p.ExitCode;

       if (killOnTimeout)
       {
           p.Kill();
       }
       else
       {
           p.CloseMainWindow();
       }

       throw new TimeoutException(string.Format("Time allotted for executing `{0}` has expired ({1} ms).", batchFilePath, timeout));
   }
}
```

*UPDATE* If you are executing the batch file form a windows service, then normally you have to disable the user interface. You can do so following this pattern:

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo(exePath); //exePath must be full path.
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.UseShellExecute = false;
Process.Start(info);
```

Comment: I have tried those codes already. Problem is When i execute the batch file through Windows command prompt it is running with in 1 min. But if i execute through code it is not finishing. I dont know how long it takes to execute though code. I waited for nearly 5 mins.

Comment: @user3859666 Again, do you need special privilidges to run the batch file? Admin rights? `Process.Start` is equivalent to the window's run command, there shouldn't be any difference.

Comment: No.. I have run the Batch file and Code in same Machine. I did not give any access previledges while running the command through Windows run.

Comment: Problem is Windows Service. I can able to run the batch file through normal Windows form application. But when i used the same code in Windows Service the Process is not Exiting. Pls help.. Its Urgent

Comment: @user3859666 See update to answer. Hope it helps. You should have said it was a window service.

Comment: I have edited with my code, See UPDATED RESPONSE. I am getting Exit Code as 1. Error is "Fatal Error : Server unexpectedly closed network connection". But i can able to run through windows command.

Comment: If you want the command window to open and show you the process, you can use **info.CreateNoWindow = false;** Hope it helps.